# pdfjs can't view PDF when containing non standard characeters

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

**SOLUTION:** To make the HTML code work, swap "reader.readAsText"
for "reader.readAsBinaryString" as explained in @KJ's answer

I am trying to view a PDF using PDFJS. I have the following code which works fine for a demo PDF I got from the PDFJS website, however it doesn't work for other PDFs I have tried. Here is the raw text of the demo PDF that works:

```
%PDF-1.7
1 0 obj  % entry point
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj<</Type/Pages/MediaBox[ 0 0 200 200]/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>>endobj
3 0 obj<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1 4 0 R>>>>/Contents 5 0 R>>endobj
4 0 obj<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Times-Roman>>endobj
5 0 obj  % page content
<</Length 44>> stream
BT 70 50 TD /F1 12 Tf(Hello, world!) Tj ET
endstream endobj
xref trailer <</Size 6/Root 1 0 R>> startxref
%%EOF
```

And here is my html code that successfully loads the above PDF:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.2.228/pdf.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="input"/> </br> <canvas id="can" width=1000 height=1000/>
<script>
    document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', function(e){
        var reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = function(x){
            window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'].getDocument({data:x.target.result}).promise.then(function(pdf){
                pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page){
                    page.render({canvasContext:document.getElementById('can').getContext('2d'),
                        viewport:page.getViewport({scale:1})})
        })})}
        reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0])
    }, false)
</script>
```

However, other PDFs of mine won't load at all. For example, I generated a 1 page PDF containing only the word 'TEST' on overleaf and downloaded it. When I tried uploading this PDF to my html code I got these errors in the console:

```
Warning: Invalid stream: "FormatError: Bad FCHECK in flate stream: 120, 253"
util.js:306 Warning: Indexing all PDF objects
2util.js:306 Warning: Invalid stream: "FormatError: Bad FCHECK in flate stream: 120, 253"
viewPDF.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) InvalidPDFException {name: "InvalidPDFException", message: "Invalid PDF structure"}
Promise.then (async)
reader.onload @ viewPDF.html:7
load (async)
(anonymous) @ viewPDF.html:6
```

I suspect the problem I am having are related to the fact that the PDFs that aren't working contain non standard characters. Here is the first few lines of the PDF from overleaf:

````
%PDF-1.5
%���
3 0 obj
<< /Linearized 1 /L 11602 /H [ 678 125 ] /O 7 /E 11072 /N 1 /T 11321 >>
endobj

4 0 obj
<< /Type /XRef /Length 51 /Filter /FlateDecode /DecodeParms << /Columns 4 /Predictor 12 >> /W [ 1 2 1 ] /Index [ 3 14 ] /Info 1 0 R /Root 5 0 R /Size 17 /Prev 11322                 /ID [<8f1689fb6a16051fd66ebeadaa364b8d><4a8030207ba6597007a967ed52a9309d>] >>
stream
x�cbd�g`b`8 $��XF@���*��    ��@�Y�����v�#�.
endstream
endobj

5 0 obj
<< /Pages 14 0 R /Type /Catalog >>
endobj
6 0 obj
<< /Filter /FlateDecode /S 36 /Length 48 >>
stream
x�c```e``Z��
            pe31
                B�����,��v�>aW�
````

**EDIT:**

The PDF from overleaf can be viewed fine in Firefox, Chromium, mac's preview app, etc. In this sense the PDF is correctly formatted. In general, I would like to be able to work with PDFs that are correctly formatted in the sense that they can be viewed by standard PDF viewers. If it is the case that PDFJS can only work with PDFs that are formatted correctly in some stricter sense, then this seems to me like either as bug in PDFJS or a lack of functionality. If this is the case I'd like of an alternative to PDFJS that I might try using instead. I suspect this is not the case however and would like to if I am in fact incorrectly handing the uploaded file to PDFJS, which would cause the problem I am having.

To give you some more context, my goal is to build a simple html app that would allow a user to upload any PDF of theirs and view it. As can be seen here: 'https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js#online-demo' it seems to work with a variety of PDFs, however I have been unable to make it work myself.

In particular, I want the user to be able to view any PDF that would be viewable in standard PDF viewers such as web-browsers (eg: firefox etc). I want the PDFs to be loaded from the users local computer, not given as a url link. I hope this clarification helps. If there are any questions please let me know. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR jump to the end.

Your outputting encoded binary streams as seen by those symbols, and as you make a PDF more complex they would be required more and more for math fonts, images and normal imbedded fonts. It is possible to output them in ascii code and be acceptable as long as all the outputs are indexed. Your overleaf code is also complicated more by output as WEB /Linearized.

The structure of a PDF is not simple and your minimal working example should look something more like this where an xref table is included.

```
%PDF-1.7
%µ¶

1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/MediaBox[0 0 200 200]/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1 4 0 R>>>>/Contents 5 0 R>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Times-Roman>>
endobj

5 0 obj
<</Length 63>>
stream
q
BT
-50 TL
/F1 12 Tf
1 0 0 1 70 50 Tm
(Hello, world!) Tj
ET
Q

endstream
endobj

xref
0 6
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000062 00000 n 
0000000136 00000 n 
0000000227 00000 n 
0000000293 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 6/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
405
%%EOF
```

The main problem with this format is the decimal byte addresses need to be correct so different OS line endings between \n \r\n and \r in a large file can alter those values drastically, such that one byte wrong and the file is corrupted.

InvalidPDFException normally means one of two things A) bad PDF B) bad pdf handling IF you know the pdf is 100% valid (never a certainty) then it must be B) Binary is somewhere parsed as ASCII text type however some jslibs expect / accept PDF as text.base64 then do the conversion client side to binary.pdf

The error suggests the binary flated data has been corrupted by ascii processing presumably in transmission or on receipt not stored as application/pdf data since parts of a pdf are encoded just like a zip file

Finally

[image]

In discussion I noted the last line of script says readAsText() and those ascii based PDFs were working, whilst testing many variations in the script above in different browsers (trying to clear console comments) the simplest solution I tested in all (except IE11 would not play ball) was to replace that with `reader.readAsBinaryString(e.target.files[0])`. However I suggest using a more complete cross browser example that handles passwords etc. would be better for others, but if it works for you, its good enough.

Comment: Thanks for providing me with another tester PDF. I tried it and it works fine with my PDFJS html page. However I still don't know how to fix the html page so that it will also accept my other PDFs. For example, what can I do to my html code so that the PDF I got from overleaf also works? Thanks again.

Comment: I think the PDFs aren't "bad" because I can open them fine on my mac in Firefox. I have code that reads in the PDF file and then passes it to the PDFJS code. Should I do some pre-processing on it to make sure its in the right format? If so, what kind of pre-processing can I do?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. It seems to me that PDFJS should be capable of reading a PDF if my browsers (firefox,chrome etc) are capable of reading the PDF. Also, hte PDF viewer 'preview' on my mac can read the PDFs fine. Is the fact that PDFJS can't read these PDFs a bug or just a lack of functionality? Or is there an easy modification I can make to my JS code so that it will work?

Comment: I could be wrong, however I don't this this is an OS dependent problem. If you want to try out recreating my problem I think you could just take the HTML code I gave, put it in a file, and open the file in any browser, then try viewing any PDF of yours. In particular you could view a PDF downloaded from overleaf. If you manage to view such a PDF from overleaf, then maybe my problem does have something to do with my OS, however I suspect not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238753/discussion-between-mathew-and-k-j).